# Programatically saving customer and address in the same controller

Tags: customer, controllers, customer-address

Is it possible to save the customer details as well as the address details in the same controller? When I try, it fails saying "customer email is required".

Here's my code:

```
$customer = Mage::getModel("customer/customer");
$customer   ->setWebsiteId($websiteId)
        ->setStore($store)
        ->setFirstname('John')
        ->setLastname('Doe')
        ->setEmail('jd1@ex.com')
        ->setPassword('somepassword');

$address = Mage::getModel("customer/address");
$address->setCustomerId($customer->getId())
    ->setFirstname($customer->getFirstname())
    ->setMiddleName($customer->getMiddlename())
    ->setLastname($customer->getLastname())
    ->setPostcode('Test')
    ->setCity('Test')
    ->setTelephone('01234567890')
    ->setFax('01234567890')
    ->setCompany('Test')
    ->setStreet('Kersov')
    ->setIsDefaultBilling('1')
    ->setIsDefaultShipping('1')
    ->setSaveInAddressBook('1');

try {
    $customer->save();
    $address->save();
}
catch (Exception $e) {
    Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->addError('There has been a problem with your registration. ' . $e->getMessage());
}
```

If I comment out `$address->save()` it successfully saves the customer (but obviously not the address).

Comment: What if you do `setCustomer($customer)` instead of `setCustomerId(...)`? It would improve performance because your object is already loaded, but I wonder if it wouldn't solve your issue too. Something spooky must be happening when the model is loaded

Comment: It should not work. you have used `$customer->getId()` to set in address model. but still that id doesn't exit. You should save csutomer first then load customer model to get id and then you can save address.

Comment: @Liam McArthur I have posted working code. Please check It should work for you as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try below code. it will work. in your code you have used customer id which still doesn't exit. id will generate after save customer.

```
$websiteId = Mage::app()->getWebsite()->getId();
$store = Mage::app()->getStore();

$customer = Mage::getModel("customer/customer");
$customer   ->setWebsiteId($websiteId)
            ->setStore($store)
            ->setFirstname('John')
            ->setLastname('Doe')
            ->setEmail('jd11@ex.com')
            ->setPassword('somepassword');         
    $customer->save();


$address = Mage::getModel("customer/address");
$address->setCustomerId($customer->getId())
    ->setFirstname($customer->getFirstname())
    ->setMiddleName($customer->getMiddlename())
    ->setLastname($customer->getLastname())
    ->setPostcode('Test')
    ->setCity('Test')
    ->setTelephone('01234567890')
    ->setFax('01234567890')
    ->setCompany('Test')
    ->setStreet('Kersov')
    ->setIsDefaultBilling('1')
    ->setIsDefaultShipping('1')
    ->setSaveInAddressBook('1');    
    $address->save();
```

Hope this will help.

Comment: This makes perfect sense and works perfectly. Thank you for your swift solution!

Comment: I know all the states of the customer, How can i add the state to all the customers, my magento ver 1.9.2.3

Comment: @zus you can try setRegion() or setRegionId()